# Why can a local service not be accessed directly?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

From what I can tell, a Service can only be accessed from an Activity via an `IBinder`, `Messenger` or `AIDL`.

Why can a service instance's methods not be directly called by, for example, an activity?

For example, when the service is started, have the service save its instance in a singleton which would then be accessed by `Activity`s, allowing them to directly call the service's methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I can tell, a Service can only be accessed from an Activity via an IBinder, Messenger or AIDL.

That would depend upon what you define as "accessed". `startService()` can also be used to direct the service to perform some operation.

> Why can a service instance's methods not be directly called by, for example, an activity?

Android's component model is designed around loose coupling and replaceable implementations, where the replacements may be local or remote.

Moreover, [a service should only be running when it is actively delivering value to the user](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). As such, there will be plenty of times when the service is not yet running, and the activity would need to start or bind to the service anyway.

For example, an `IntentService` should only be interacted with via `startService()`, as the `IntentService` will only be running while there are commands (supplied via `startService()`) to be processed.

Finally, the primary role of a `Service` is as a marker to the OS, letting it know that the process is still doing work, even while it is in the background. A pattern of "let's stuff the `Service` into a singleton" suggests that you are using the service in cases where the object in question does not necessarily need to be a `Service`. Just because an object is a singleton does not mean that it needs to be a `Service`. Hence, you need to sit back and ensure you know exactly why you are using a `Service` in the first place and whether that is best for the user.

> For example, when the service is started, have the service save its instance in a singleton which would then be accessed by Activitys, allowing them to directly call the service's methods?

There's nothing stopping you from doing this. I wouldn't -- I'll use `startService()` and event buses for communications. And, while it is technically possible to do what you want, whether it is sensible and reliable depends entirely upon the use case of the service and the communications with that service.

Comment: Thanks - I don't suppose you can think of an example when "stuffing it into a singleton" would be a fair choice? What prompted me to ask the question is when using MediaPlayer that should persist playing when the screen is rotated, or when the activity is not in the foreground, (but not finished).

Comment: @Jodes: Your scenario calls for a `Service` (to keep your process around and manage the music playback in the background). I personally would not use a singleton. Bear in mind that the user can stop your service at any point while leaving your process running (see Running Apps in Settings). Hence, you cannot assume that your singleton is any good. I'd just use `startService()` to send commands to the service (and start it up as needed) to tell it requests from the UI (e.g., skip to the next track), and use an event bus to let the service inform the UI of changes (e.g., details of the track).